# Display related information in Dynamics CRM 2011 Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 solution containing a pick list for selecting a person.

I am trying to determine how I could display a summary of this person's information at the top of the form dynamically when the person is selected.

I have already set up a javascript library that is triggered 'onchange' by selecting a new person, however I have been unable to determine the best way to add the summary information (eg, name, address, phone..) to the top of the form.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to call the REST endpoint from your OnChange method and retrieve the additional details and populate them into new fields. Normally instead of a drop down, a lookup field might be a better option, this way you would have access the user id which you would need when getting the additional details, without it you would likely need to make another query to find it or have the values hard coded. You could also look as using a JavaScript inside a web resource that is embedded in the form, the additional details could be displayed in standard HTML elements without having to create additional CRM fields.

[Sample: Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete Using the REST Endpoint with JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx)